# How to split a string into array without using Array.split?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to implement Array.split() just by using loops without using any built in functions?

I want this:
`"Hello how are you"` ---> `["Hello" , "how", "are", "you"]` without using Array.split() or any built in function.

Comment: Of course it's possible. What have you tried so far? How would you approach the problem?

Comment: You can use the String.indexOf(), make an array the do a while loop, you can search for the documentation

Answer (score 2):

try this

```js
let str= "Hello how are you";
 
let array = [''];
let j = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) == " ") {
        j++;
        array.push('');
    } else {
        array[j] += str.charAt(i);
    }
}
console.log(array)
```

Comment: if answered useful mark as answers

Comment: If string start with ' ' (empty char) the first element of the array will be empty so do for the last char. So maybe a str.strip() (if there is in javascript may be used depends of the need).

Answer (score 0):

```
let word = "stack over flow murat";
let arr = []
let tempWord= ""

for (let i = 0; i<word.length; i++){
if(word[i]===" "){
    arr.push(tempWord);
    tempWord="";
}
else{
    tempWord+=word[i];
    }
}
arr.push(tempWord);
console.log(arr);
```